# Image area select to crop image in phonegap

Tags: cordova, crop, imageareaselect

I am new in phonegap.

I want to develop a app in which i want that a user will upload an image then he can crop the image through selecting image area. 
So please tell me how it's possible in phonegap.

Js plugin are not working on mobile.

please check following image to know what exactly i want.
http://media.tumblr.com/df0529ed63155df0c7fff5d816a0f9ad/tumblr_inline_msopy8ONJY1qz4rgp.jpg

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am stuck at exactly the same point. I want to crop an image on Ios application developed using Phonegap. I tried many plugins like imageAreaSelect and Jcrop, but they don't seem to work on mobile. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I tried another plugin called JCrop-http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html and it worked perfectly fine. I followed the tutorial on the demo page. I tried the imgAreaSelect plugin but got stuck. There were no browser errors or anywhere I could look for as to why it wasn't working.

Comment: I use this but its not working  my side in IOS. have you any other demo?

Comment: Can you tell specifically the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like imgAreaSelect where you can drag and crop within a window, try [Guillotine](//github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine), it's very easy to set up.

Not only allows to *crop*, *zoom* and *rotate* but it's also **responsive** (fluid) and has **touch support** which you certainly need in a mobile app.

Check out the [demo](//matiasgagliano.github.io/guillotine).